# Weird issue with signals in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, signals-slots

I have a class which inherits from `QObject`. I have a property in the class declared as

```
Q_PROPERTY(QString errorString READ errorString)
```

In QML, Qt Creator suggests an `onErrorStringChanged` signal which is clearly a read-only property. Also the same signal was missing from suggestions when I tried the `connect()` method on the object of the class in C++.

Could anyone clarify what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue. You can read about it here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#property-attributes

> Declaring a custom property implicitly creates a value-change signal
>   for that property, as well as an associated signal handler called
>   `on<PropertyName>Changed`, where `<PropertyName>` is the name of the
>   property, with the first letter capitalized.

QML automatically creates the `onErrorStringChanged` signal whereas in C++ you have to define it yourself.

Comment: Whats the point of specifying only the getter method if there is going to be a `onChanged` signal for the property? Btw I also tried with the `CONSTANT` keyword which also gave the same result. Is there any way to avoid this signal ?

Comment: The Point is simple that QML needs this signal. Quote from the docs: "Note that a NOTIFY signal must be specified to allow QML property bindings." If you do not need it simply ignoring it should work ;). You can also name your Property e.g. "errorStringConst" to show that it can not be changed.

Comment: If `errorString` is always the same, mark the property as `CONSTANT`. I doubt that's the case though. If it's capable of returning a more than one type of error message, then you have to provide a `NOTIFY` signal if you want QML bindings that refer to it to work correctly.

Comment: Typing Q_PROPERTY below Q_OBJECT prompts Qt Creator to offer a snippet with the full property declaration. Once you fill out the type and getter/setter names in the snippet, right-clicking Q_PROPERTY gives a Refactor option to generate getter/setter code. To make a constant property, before generating getter/setter code, remove the setter declaration in the Q_PROPERTY macro and replace NOTIFY and the signal name with CONSTANT, as Mitch wrote.